# How to make form in java and connect it with database

Tags: java

Hi all I have experience in dot net but now i want to move in java. Now i want to ask that how can i make form in java and connect it with MS SQL SERVER 2008 and show data on button click event. Please help me on this...

Comment: desktop, web, or mobile?

Comment: You should describe in your question whether you want to work with a mobile, web or desktop environment. By the way @user1132265, I suggest you to accept questions and/or vote them up if you find them useful in order be useful for the community with your questions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Desktop swing applications, I would suggest you use netbeans. Upon creating a form right click on an object, lets say a JButton, then add event. Also, create a class for connection.

This is a sample connection function

```
public static Connection connect(String sqlServer, String username, String password, String server, String dbName, String port) throws SQLException{

    String connString;

    switch (sqlServer) {
        case "MSSQL":
            connString = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+server+";database="+dbName+";"; 
            break;
        case "MySQL":
            connString = "jdbc:mysql://"+server+":"+port+"/"+dbName+"?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
            break;
        default:
            connString = "";
            break;
    }
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    return conn;
}
```

For displaying a result:

```
ResultSet rs = Conn.connect(<all the parameters>).createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ATABLE");
while(rs.next()){
    textfield.setText(rs.getString("Field1"));
}
```

That is a very rough code. You can visit alot of websites that offer tutorials for this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I believe this question doesn't have a straightforward answer because it strongly depends on the technology you are working or you will work with.

For instance, if you working with Servlets based pure MVC, you have to create a form in your JSP and then after submit, catch all the parameters one by one while setting the appropriate value in your entity bean and then invoke your data access object.

On the other hand, if you are using Struts or Spring MVC, roughly you only have to bind the form with your entity bean and the values are automatically filled, so you only have to worry of invoke the corresponding data access object.

I hope it helps.

Comment: if you have any tutorial then please share

Comment: @user1132265 Why have you not accepted any answer so far?

Comment: @user1132265 I could share with you a lot of resources, but first I need to know something about what you know and what are your intentions in order to give you the appropriate material. Are you tied  up to any technology or framework? Do you know anything about any Java MVC framework (Struts, JSF, Spring MVC, etc)? Do you have any knowledge about MVC, regardless it is a Java or .Net scope? As I said, your question is ambiguous and is not straight forward to answer as a consequence.